# Iterate through an array of objects, to find objects that contain 2 values

Tags: javascript

I currently have an array that looks like this:

```
var array = [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "age": 1,
        "siblings": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "b",
        "age": 3,
        "siblings": 5
      },
      {
        "name": "a",
        "age": 1,
        "siblings": 2
      }
]
```

I want to create a function that takes 2 values, and returns a new array containing the objects that match those two values.

```
var name = "a";
var age = 1;
someFunction(name, age);
```

And returns something that looks like this:

```
newArray = [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "age": 1,
        "siblings": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "a",
        "age": 1,
        "siblings": 2
      }

]
```

I have tried using the filter method and the reduce methods but no success. If someone could help me or point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate that.

```js
var array = [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "age": 1,
        "siblings": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "b",
        "age": 3,
        "siblings": 5
      },
      {
        "name": "a",
        "age": 1,
        "siblings": 2
      }
]

 var result = array.filter(function(obj) {
           return obj.name === "a" && obj.age === 1;
           });
    return result[0];
 }
console.log(result);
```

Comment: please add your try. filter is one approach.

Comment: Please post your approach using `filter`

Comment: your code has a `return` statement without a function, and you return only the first element of the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array with the wanted key/value pair for searching.

Take [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a check for the predicates with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
var array = [{ name: "a", age: 1, siblings: 3 }, { name: "b", age: 3, siblings: 5 }, { name: "a", age: 1, siblings: 2 }],
    search = [['name', 'a'], ['age', 1]],
    result = array.filter(object => search.every(([key, value]) => object[key] === value));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

here is your working function

```
function someFunction (name, age) {
    return array.filter(val => val.name == name && val.age == age)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) callback, just compare the `name` & `age` of current element with those of the params you passed.

```js
var array = [{"name":"a","age":1,"siblings":3},{"name":"b","age":3,"siblings":5},{"name":"a","age":1,"siblings":2}]
var name = "a";
var age = 1;
function someFunction(name, age){
 return array.filter((obj) => obj.name === name && obj.age === age)
}
console.log(someFunction(name, age));
```

You can also use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Just add the matching object in the accumulator array and return it.

```js
var array = [{"name":"a","age":1,"siblings":3},{"name":"b","age":3,"siblings":5},{"name":"a","age":1,"siblings":2}]
var name = "a";
var age = 1;
function someFunction(name, age){
 return array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
   if(obj.name === name && obj.age === age) 
     acc.push(obj);
   return acc;
 }, []);
}
console.log(someFunction(name, age));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter function

```js
var array = [
  {
    "name": "a",
    "age": 1,
    "siblings": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "age": 3,
    "siblings": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "a",
    "age": 1,
    "siblings": 2
  }
]
var name = "a";
var age = 1;
someFunction(name, age);
function someFunction(name,age)
{
console.log(array.filter((e)=>e.name==name && e.age==age?true:false
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let array = [
  {
    "name": "a",
    "age": 1,
    "siblings": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "age": 3,
    "siblings": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "a",
    "age": 1,
    "siblings": 2
  }
];

function someFunction(name, age) {
  let newArray = [];
  array.forEach(function(arr) {
    let nameMatch = false;
    let ageMatch = false;
    let obj = arr;
    for(key in obj) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(key === 'name') {
          // console.log('name key i am', key);
          let nameValue = obj[key];
          if(nameValue === name) {
            nameMatch = true;
            // console.log('name match', nameValue, name);
          }
        } else if(key === 'age') {
          let ageValue = obj[key];
          if(ageValue === age) {
             // console.log('age match', ageValue, age);
             ageMatch = true
          }
        }
      } 
    }
    if(ageMatch &&  nameMatch) {
      // console.log('true');
      newArray.push(arr);
      // console.log(arr);
    }
  });

  return newArray;
}

let name = "a";
let age = 1;
let myArr = someFunction(name, age);
console.log('My Arr', myArr);
```